# How can Upload HTML content on Google Cloud for Node js project?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-node

I'm new to Google Cloud  and I want to build 1 website using Node js. For now I just want to upload my HTML template on Google Cloud so I can see only the HTML part of project by using a URL, any help appreciated.

below is app.yalm file's content

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two easy options:

- [Hosting a static website with Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) (easy and quick, but very limited)
- Use [App Engine standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/quickstart) (more configuraiton options and easy to develop on)

Comment: I've followed https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website?authuser=1  and deployed my html page on server and URL is https://brsystem.appspot.com/ but it's giving Error 404,

Comment: @sohelshaikh Go to [your project's services](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/services) and click in the service name (it's probably `default`). You'll get redirected to the website. If you still have problems, they're probably related to the [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref)

Comment: when I goto project's services and click on service name it redirect me to same URL https://brsystem.appspot.com/ but still not working,

Comment: @sohelshaikh Then the issue is comming from the app.yaml or other thing related to the deployment. As it's not related to your original question you should work on it by yourself. If after trying you are still stuck, then you can create another question for it